# how to modify my Core Data attributes of an entity but on all the elements of my database

Tags: swift

hello community I am a novice and this is my first question.
how to change all the attributes of an entity and be able to change all my Core Data elements,
because I can only change the first attribute of an entity but not all my data records.

Here in this function I can only change the name
and then I get this following error has the line:

```
let objectUpdate = test[0] : Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

---

```
func updateData() {

    var newName = ""
    var newPrenom = ""

    newName = name.text!
    newPrenom = prenom.text!

    let managedContext =  AppDelegate.viewContext
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Person")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", newName)
    do {
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "prenom = %@", newPrenom)

        let test = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
        let objectUpdate = test[0]

        objectUpdate.setValue(newName,forKey: "name")
        objectUpdate.setValue(newPrenom, forKey: "prenom")
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means your fetch request didn’t return any values. You should do something like `if test.isEmpty { return }` before the row that gives you the error

Comment: Can you post the code of your `Person` CoreDataProperties?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways we can avoid this error.

#### Unwrapping optional `.first` value

Swift's [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) gives us safe way to get first item, simply by accessing the `first` property on a given collection. It will return an `Optional<Element>` value so we need to unwrap it first either by using `if let` of `guard let`

```swift
if let object = test.first {
    // do something with object
}
```

or

```swift
guard let object = test.first else { return }
// do something with object
```

#### Checking if value at index exists

It's often a good idea to check for a specific index within the `indices` property before accessing the value behind it.

```swift
if test.indices.contains(0) {
    let object = test[0]
    // do something with object
}
```

These hints should prevent your code from crashing again.

## Other Suggestions

This is not really safe or clean:

```swift
var newName = ""
var newPrenom = ""

newName = name.text!
newPrenom = prenom.text!
```

We can make it much cleaner and most importantly safer by using a `guard` statement

```swift
guard let newName = name.text, let newPrenom = prenom.text else { return }
```

Two important things happened here:

1. No more force-unwrapping the optional values of `text` [which could cause a crash]
2. The properties are now immutable, meaning we can be sure that what we are saving to the CoreDate is what was retreived at the beginning of the function

---

Since the line:

```swift
let test = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

is already wrapped in the `do-catch` clause, you can safely remove forced `try!` and replace it with `try`.

```swift
let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

---

Let's use types! On this line you create a `NSFetchRequest` object for some entity named `"Person"`.

```swift
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Person")
```

I am guessing CoreData have generated for you a `NSManagedObject` subclass, named `Person`. If this is true, you could rewrite it like this:

```swift
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
```

---

With the previous tip implemented, we can now get rid of `as! [NSManagedObject]` from this line:

```swift
let test = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

Since the `NSFetchRequest` object is now nicely typed, we can take advantage of it by rewriting it like this:

```swift
let test: [Person] = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

---

So we are using proper types now? cool! Lets now improve this:

```swift
objectUpdate.setValue(newName,forKey: "name")
objectUpdate.setValue(newPrenom, forKey: "prenom")
```

by rewriting this and using properties on `Person` object

```swift
objectUpdate.name = newName
objectUpdate.prenom = newPrenom
```

---

No need for introducing second level of `do-catch` clause, since we are already in one!

```swift
do {
    try managedContext.save()
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

you can easily replace it with just the `save()` call, like this:

```swift
try managedContext.save()
```

---

Are you sure these predicates are what you want?

```swift
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", newName)
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "prenom = %@", newPrenom)
```

What I can read from them is that you are fetching `Person` object where the name is `newName` and prenom is `newPrenom` and then you update it with the same exact values? Are you using some kind of identification of users? like `id: Int` or `id: UUID`? It would make much more sense to write something like this

```swift
let id: Int = // ID of the user you are currently editing 
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(id)")
```

if you are not using any id's, you could try storing the initial values of `name` and `prenom`

```swift
// in cell declaration - set when you configure your cell
var initialName: String?
var initialPrenom: String? 
// then in your function:
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", initialName)
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "prenom = %@", initialPrenom)
```

But I just noticed you also override you first predicate with the second one. You need to use [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate)

```swift
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
    type: .and, subpredicates: [
        NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", initialName),
        NSPredicate(format: "prenom = %@", initialPrenom)
    ]
)
```

## Suggested version

```swift
func updateData() {
    guard let newName = name.text, let newPrenom = prenom.text else { return }
    let managedContext = AppDelegate.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(
        type: .and, subpredicates: [
            NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", initialName),
            NSPredicate(format: "prenom = %@", initialPrenom)
        ]
    )
    do {
        let objects: [Person] = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        guard let object = objects.first else { return }
        object.name = newName
        object.prenom = newPrenom
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I made the small changes but I can only change the name and the first name.
On all my elements saved in my TableView I can only change the name of each cell

Comment: I have just updated the answer, check out the part where I talk about your predicates. They do not make much sense to me

Comment: For the id I am not understood but for the rest I tried as you indicated to me exactly and the result is that I can just change the name of each person to register example:
I recorded in:
Name: Kope
First name: Bryan

When I run the update I can only edit Kope and not Bryan.

I can therefore only change all the names of each person and not all the elements

Comment: Lets forget about the id for now. You should be using old names in the predicate, not new. New are not yet saved so there is No way you would fetch the object you want this way. Try to store the old name and prenom when you configure the view and later use these values for the predicate.

Comment: Hello sorry to come back to you again I have tried several things.
You are right about the predicate that is where the error comes from.
in summary I can not change the name is not the first name.
example if my TableView has 15 people.
I could change the name of all these people but I want to change the name and surname of each person

Comment: you were overriding the first predicate with the second one. Please read updated answer there I initially talked about using ID

Answer (score -1):

If the index 0 is out of range, it means that the array is empty. Before accessing it, add

```
if test.isEmpty{
   return //the fetch request didn't return any values
}
```